# AJAX and Shortcode with Parameters

Tags: shortcode, ajax

I'm creating an ajax function which will display a filtered post. I used a shortcode to display the post.

The shortcode has a parameter to filter its display. I have a category and a tag parameter. Now when I type manually the shortcode it's working fine, but when I render it to the Ajax, the output is zero(0).

Here is the code in the footer.php

[image]

and in the function.php

[image]

I hope this makes sense.

Also, this is the HTML layout.

[image]